Variable dice simulation total

I've created dice in Excel, but now I'm trying to calculate the value of the dice based on x amount of dice. ie if I want 3d6, it only pulls values of 3 dice instead of all 15. Would I use COUNTIF or how else do I go about this?
Edit: I have no clue how to share an excel file, if someone tells me how I will.

Help us help you, and share the spreadsheet you already have.

How are the dice generated? Do you want 3 random values, or just the first 3?

@Excellor I want the dice to be in numeric order so I can tell if I have exploding dice

So you want the dice numeric representations in order? Like =SORT(TOCOL(INDEX($1:$1048576,{14;18;22},SEQUENCE(,20,6)),1)) ?

Seems like a frame challenge to me. As it is now you are doing "extra calculations" for those "unused dice". I would probably get rid of the visual representation and have two fields one for number of dice and the second field for number of dice sides. From this you can build your array of dice and sum the dice rolls relatively easily.
